# What are the essential security tests for a blockchain?

Tags: security, blockchain, cryptocurrency

What are the essential security tests for a blockchain?
I mean if I wanna be assure about security of a particular blockchain (either PoW or PoS), what kind of test I should do?
any source, link hint, tip or comment is welcomed.

Comment: I suggest adding some more detail on what area you're looking to secure -- this question is a bit too broad in its current form. For example: verifying transactions (blocks), or verifying nodes (participants on the network) versus verifying proof of work (core) all have different answers.

Comment: In general you want to prevent double spends. This is a way for someone to theoretically have infinite money. If you are trying to use "blockchain" for something other than digital currency, then you might need to reevaluate.

Comment: @IshanChatterjee
I posted a complete version of my question here 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62113965/can-we-establish-a-blockchain-precisely-dag-as-an-infrastructure-of-a-cryptocu

Comment: @JBaczuk
I posted a complete version of my question here 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62113965/can-we-establish-a-blockchain-precisely-dag-as-an-infrastructure-of-a-cryptocu